# Vala async closure

Tags: asynchronous, closures, gtk, vala

I am trying to make a async closure because I call another async function inside. Some I am trying to do something like this:

```cs
void connect_on_button_click () {
    some_button.connect (() => {
        var val = yield some_async_function ();
        // Do something with the value...
    });
}
```

But vala compiler gives error.
So currently my solution is passing a defined async function such as:

```cs
async void on_button_click () {
    var val = yield some_async_function ();
    // Do something with the value...
}

void connect_on_button_click () {
    some_button.connect (on_button_click);
}
```

But I wonder if it is possible to mark a closure as async so I don't have to create another function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async lambdas/closures/delegates currently [aren't supported](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/-/issues/66).

However if your example above reflects your actual use case then you don't actually need them, you just need to use the [`async_method.begin(…)` form](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Asynchronous_Methods) to call the async method:

```
void connect_on_button_click () {
    some_button.connect (() => {
        some_async_function.begin();
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually it wasn't reflecting my actual use case because I was using the return value of the async function. I have updated the queestion accordingly. Since vala doesn't support it I am going to accept it if you have not any suggestion for my use case.

Comment: In that case (whether or not vala supports async lambdas etc) the solution is basically the same as above, because signal handler contexts are not async either. So typically you'll need an extra async `on_button_click` method/function that makes the async calls you actually need to do, and call it using `begin`.

Comment: I see your point. So basically the signal doesn't expect an async function so passing one doesn't really work as expected I think? Even though it seemed to work in my use case.

Comment: Pretty much, yep.